# how to get table info and summary of page using Wikipedia api?

Tags: wikipedia-api

I want to get minimal information of a Wikipedia page using MediaWiki API like `DuckDuckGo`. For example for Steve Carell: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=steve+carell&t=hp&ia=news&iax=about

How can I get this information with a Wikipedia url (eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Carell) in `HTML` format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the MediaWiki API for that. There's an extension, TextExtracts, which is exactly for that (and it is installed on Wikipedia).

In your case, e.g.:
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&exsentences=1&titles=Steve%20Carell

will return something like:

```
<p class=\"mw-empty-elt\">\n</p>\n\n<p class=\"mw-empty-elt\">\n \n</p>\n<p><b>Steven John Carell</b> (<span></span>; born August 16, 1962) is an American actor, comedian, producer, writer and director.</p>
```

You can customize how many sentences (or characters) the API returns, as well, please consult the [API documentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bextracts) for that.

There's also the way to retrieve the short description, which is saved at Wikidata (and visible in the mobile view of Wikipedia). This call would be:
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageprops&titles=Steve_Carell

This returns the following property in the pageprops of the page:

```
"wikibase-shortdesc": "American actor"
```

This may fit better depending on your use case.

You can even get both of the results with a single, combined, request:
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts|pageprops&exsentences=1&titles=Steve_Carell

Comment: can I get both of them in one request?

Comment: Of course. I edited my answer with the request to retrieve both results in a single request.

Comment: The [summary API](https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/#/Page%20content/get_page_summary__title_) gives significantly better extracts than TextExtracts.

Comment: ah, yeah, didn't think about the summary API :/